# Using an icon to accompany text for better conversions

Tags: conversion, experience, conversion-rate

I have an add to cart button on my products page, and I am trying to decide if it is better to have an icon or not.

[image: current button with icon]

This is what my current button looks like, but I see companies like Walmart just have text no icons. Does anyone have any ideas as to what is better for conversion. I thought the icon would help attract people's eyes to it better, and immediately understand what the button would do, before they even read the text.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say if an icon will increase conversions! It highly depends on the audience, the site, and how/when someone sees the button. Even a case study from another company won't be very helpful because it will only tell you what worked for them.

**Try a Simple A/B Test**

- **A:** Product page with "add to cart" button (no icon)
- **B:** Product page with "add to cart" button (icon)

Good luck!